# Opening and Saving Word Document to new File Location from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to open a word document from excel and then save as to a new file location using a dialog box.

**The problem is it saves the excel file rather than the word file that was opened.**

```
Option Explicit
Sub SaveWordDoc()
    Dim WordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object, path As String
    Dim dlgSaveAs As FileDialog

    ' Allows word document to be selected and opened
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
        path = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    End With

    If path = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If


    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(path)
    WordApp.Visible = False

    'Opens Save As dialog box
    Set dlgSaveAs = Application.FileDialog( _
    FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    dlgSaveAs.Show

    WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close
    WordApp.Quit
    Set WordApp = Nothing
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application` in `Application.FileDialog` refers to the Excel instance. If you want to continue using dialog boxes within Excel (as opposed to leveraging the `WordApp` instance), perhaps try the [`Application.GetSaveAsFilename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getsaveasfilename) method, which gets a filename without saving any files. Then use the filename it returns to save `WordDoc` using the [`SaveAs2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.saveas2) method.

Comment: Try 'Set dlgSaveAs = WordApp.Application.FileDialog( _
    FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    dlgSaveAs.Show' to use a filedialog.  To just save the word document to the same folder you got it from use WordDoc.SaveAs2.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you BigBen your suggestion works well as long as the a word document format is selected.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim WordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object, path As String
    Dim dlgSaveAs As FileDialog, fileSaveName As Variant

    ' To get the code to function I had to include the Microsoft Word 16 Object
    'Library.

    'From the excel VBA editor window. Tools > References then ensure Microsoft Word
    '16.0 Object Library is checked.

    ' Allows word document to be selected and opened
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
        path = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    End With

    If path = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If


    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(path)
    WordApp.Visible = False

    ' Allows word document to be saved under a different file location and name
    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    fileFilter:="Word Documents (*.docx), *.docx")
    WordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=fileSaveName, _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault

    WordApp.ActiveDocument.Close
    WordApp.Quit

    Set WordApp = Nothing
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```